# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 as a double boot with Windows 10 on separate drive

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have a 64-bit machine with two HDDs both partitioned into two 500Gb drives. I have Windows 10 (upgrade from 7) on 'C', but want to install U14.04LTS on the second HDD's first partition ('E'). I have a DVD of the iso, and can get as far as 'something else' in the install instructions, but there is no 'EFI' option when I try to partition the 'E' Drive. Ihave used Ubunutu before but this has me flumoxed.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to solve your problem is to give you a nearly complete install instruction.

Generally it is recommended to install all operating systems to the same disk.
If  you want to install Ubuntu to another disk you can do it nevertheless.
Important is to install all boot loaders to the same (EFI) partition which already exists.

First you will have to **disable hibernation** and **Fast Boot** in your **Windows 10 installation**.
Boot into Windows, open **command prompt as administrator** and execute this command:

```
powercfg /h off
```

To disable Fast Boot open **Control Panel** (the old version - not the modern design),
select the **Energy Settings**, enable **show hidden settings** and **uncheck Fast Boot**.

**Shutdown** the machine (do **NOT reboot**) completely.

Now boot from the Ubuntu installation media and select **Try Ubuntu without installing**.

Launch the installation process by clicking **Install Ubuntu** on the desktop.

When asked choose **Something else** - select the disk and partition where to install Ubuntu
(in your case this would the second drive and the first partition - it should be named sdb1).

Then select the disk and partition to install the GRUB boot loader.
(in your case this would be the first drive, it should be named sda)
**GRUB** will **automatically** be installed to the **efi partition** on sda.

Start the installation process and when it finished reboot:

Boot into BIOS and change the boot order in UEFI settings.
Select Ubuntu to be the default operating system to boot.
Now you can select which system to boot from GRUB menu.

Note:

If you are not sure about disks and partitions - you can identify them with **GParted**.
This tool with a graphical user interface is included in the Ubuntu installation media.